# Applying gaussian blur on RGBA images

Tags: python, python-3.x, array, image, numpy

I designed the code and it works quite well for images of lower res. However my program takes a lot of time and ram to display higher res images (occupies 2GB RAM for 4k images and takes 20 minutes). This program currently only processes files in .png format.

```
#------------------------------------
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import skimage 
from skimage import color
import numpy as np
#------------------------------------
x=plt.imread("s2.png")    #the file name
#x=color.rgba2rgb(x)
y=x
n=int(input())     #"n" is the level of blurring(typical values=5,10,20,50)
le=y.shape[0]
bd=y.shape[1]
#------------------------------------
def frame(y):
    y2=np.ones(shape=(le+(2*n),bd+(2*n)))
    for i in range(0,le):
        for j in range(0,bd):
            y2[(i+n),(j+n)]=y[i,j]
    return(y2)
#------------------------------------
#print((frame(y[:,:,0])).shape)

p=(2*n)+1
def kernel(p):

    k=np.zeros(shape=(p,p))
    for i in range(0,p):
        for j in range(0,p):
            k[i,j]=1.00005**(-(n-i)**2-(n-j)**2)
    k=k/(np.sum(k))
    return(k)
#print(kernel(p).shape)
#------------------------------------

def blur(arr,k,y2):
    z=np.zeros(shape=(le,bd))
    for i in range(0,le):
        for j in range(0,bd):
            z[i,j]=np.sum(k*(y2[i:(i+n+2+n-1),j:(j+n+2+n-1)]))

    return(z)
#------------------------------------
r=blur(y[:,:,0],kernel(p),frame(y[:,:,0]))
g=blur(y[:,:,1],kernel(p),frame(y[:,:,1]))
b=blur(y[:,:,2],kernel(p),frame(y[:,:,2]))

x2=(np.array([r.transpose(),g.transpose(),b.transpose()])).transpose()
plt.imshow(x2)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Python is slow. If you want to speed this up, try using Numba, or try rewriting in a compiled language. However, the better approach (if you’re not writing code to learn) is to use a pre-existing implementation of the convolution. Scikit has several (in sub-packages ndimage, signal, etc).

Answer (score 4):

Before we get into deep performance concerns, let's do a quality pass:

### Global code

Lines like

```
x=plt.imread("s2.png")    #the file name
#x=color.rgba2rgb(x)
y=x
n=int(input())     #"n" is the level of blurring(typical values=5,10,20,50)
le=y.shape[0]
bd=y.shape[1]
```

should be in a function and not in global scope.

### Mystery input

Pass a prompt to `input`, such as `Please enter the level of blurring`.

### Extraneous parens

This:

```
y2=np.ones(shape=(le+(2*n),bd+(2*n)))
for i in range(0,le):
    for j in range(0,bd):
        y2[(i+n),(j+n)]=y[i,j]
return(y2)
```

can be

```
y2 = np.ones(shape=(le + 2*n, bd + 2*n))
for i in range(le):
    for j in range(bd):
        y2[i + n, j + n] = y[i, j]
return y2
```

Also note the default value for the start of `range`.

### In-place division

This:

```
k=k/(np.sum(k))
return(k)
```

can be

```
k /= np.sum(k)
return k
```

### Empty, not zero

Your `blur` method should definitely be vectorized, which I'll get to later, but for now, since it's clear that you're overwriting every entry: use `empty` rather than `zeros`.

### Add another dimension

This:

```
r=blur(y[:,:,0],kernel(p),frame(y[:,:,0]))
g=blur(y[:,:,1],kernel(p),frame(y[:,:,1]))
b=blur(y[:,:,2],kernel(p),frame(y[:,:,2]))
```

should not be three separate calls. Your data should have a dimension (`y` already does) of length 3, and `y` should be passed in its entirety.

### Variable names

`le`, `bd` and `p` mean nothing to me, and in three months they might not mean anything to you, either. Write these out with longer, more meaningful names. I promise that it will not slow the program down.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the flaws in quality. Would be great if you could give some tips for performance enhancement since the program is really slow.